# Rails/Ruby incorrectly showing variable not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In debugging console, while app running (using binding.pry to interrupt it), I can see that my variable `Rails.configuration.hardcoded_current_user_key` is set:

```
pry(#<TasksController>)> Rails.configuration.hardcoded_current_user_key
=> "dev"
```

But it doesn't appear to be ***defined:***

```
pry(#<TasksController>)> defined?(Rails.configuration.hardcoded_current_user_key)
=> nil
```

Yet it works fine to store and test its value:

```
pry(#<TasksController>)> tempVar = Rails.configuration.hardcoded_current_user_key
=> "dev"
pry(#<TasksController>)> defined?(tempVar)
=> "local-variable"
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Rails config [implements](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/797f1dd63c68eb44c1af358d377cfef271e685c5/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb#L83) `respond_to?` but not `respond_to_missing?`, and `defined?` only [recognizes](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/f0548a9a0bb7271f334a30d7c34dbd56a8764189/language/defined_spec.rb#L107) `respond_to_missing?`:

```rb
class X
  def respond_to?(name, include_all = false)
    name == :another_secret || super
  end

  private

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    case name
    when :super_secret
      'Bingo!'
    when :another_secret
      'Nope.'
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(name, include_all = false)
    name == :super_secret || super
  end
end

x = X.new
puts x.super_secret          # => Bingo!
p defined?(x.super_secret)   # => "method"
puts x.another_secret        # => Nope.
p defined?(x.another_secret) # => nil
```

It's [recommended](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding) to implement `respond_to_missing?` along with `method_missing`, I too wonder why Rails did it that way.

Comment: Thanks, I'm struggling to wrap my brain around this!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `defined?` on anything but the "stub" of that, or in other words, merely this:

```
defined?(Rails)
```

Anything beyond that is highly unusual to see, and I'm not even sure it's valid.

`defined?` is not a method, but a construct that tests if the following thing is defined as a variable, constant or method, among other things. It won't *evaluate* your code, it will just test it as-is. This means method calls don't happen, and as such, can't be chained.

If you want to test that something is *assigned*, then you should use this:

```
Rails.configuration.hardcoded_current_user_key.nil?
```

Comment: It is valid; for example: `defined? Rails`, `defined? Rails.configuration`, `defined? Rails.configuration.time_zone`, `defined? String.new.length`, and `String.new.pancakes` are all fine and yield the expected value. `defined? Rails.configuration.custom_env_thing` says `nil` even though `Rails.configuration.custom_env_thing` works. I wonder if there is some `method_missing?` trickery going on.

Comment: @muistooshort Could be the case, where it's not actually a method. I've seen some Rails proxy classes that are frustratingly transparent.

Comment: But if `Rails.configuration.hardcoded_current_user_key` **can** be evaluated, doesn't that mean it is a variable, constant or method? Is there no way to check if a given dot-resolved thing (I'm not even sure what to call these) exists? `.nil?` doesn't cut it, because I might define `a` and set it to `nil`, but never define `b`... there must be some way to tell after the fact that `a` is defined and assigned but `b` is not without crashing rails!

Comment: The `defined?(...)` method is intended for constants where referencing them would cause an exception. Normally you test variables versus `nil` or whatever expected result using regular logic. Try to avoid using `defined?(...)` unless you're testing for the presence of a module, class or constant.